# React-native (Signed) release apk keeps crashing in device

Tags: android-studio, react-native, apk

I created a signed react-native apk after following all the documents from the official react native documentation ( i.e. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android ). After creating it my app crashed.

Taking a step back, I decided to make a new un-edited app and redo the same steps. However, the app still crashed. I looked at all the discussions at StackOverflow and tried their solution but none worked. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? And how I can solve it.

Here is my build.gradle:

(In the gradle, Android studio does warn me about **Cannot resolve symbol 'build'** but that hasn't affected my app in the virtual device )

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

and this is my gradle.properties:
(I have replaced the actual passwords with *****)

```js
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=******
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=******
```

And I also used Logcat and found the following error when I opened the app in my android device:

```js
2019-02-13 12:39:48.479 16607-16607/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-02-13 12:39:48.479 16607-16607/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-02-13 12:39:48.480 16607-16607/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2019-02-13 12:39:48.770 2979-3049/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{17ca770 u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.sec.android.app.launcher.activities.LauncherActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:517 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.stepAppWindowsAnimation:1745 
2019-02-13 12:39:48.771 2979-3049/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{a96df36 u0 Splash Screen com.newproject EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21578:476 
2019-02-13 12:39:48.807 16607-16623/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.newproject, PID: 16607
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:226)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:32)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:253)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1152)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:123)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:943)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-02-13 12:39:48.919 4373-4787/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[19234207413972827] not persisted.
2019-02-13 12:39:49.205 2979-3049/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{4d42d2f u0 com.newproject/com.newproject.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21578:476 
2019-02-13 12:39:50.498 2979-2999/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
```

Comment: You really need to post a crash log. You can get one from your device by plugging your phone into your computer, open the app so it crashes, then run `adb logcat -d > logs.txt` in the terminal it will save a file called `logs.txt` to your computer. You need to look through that log to find the error that is causing your app to crash. You then need to copy that error, edit your questions, and paste in the error.

Comment: @Andrew Is there any way to use abd logcat without root?

Comment: You shouldn't need to root your device. you are running `adb logact` in a terminal on your computer. You just need to make sure that usb debugging is enabled

Comment: @Andrew My bad. The documentation I was referring to was faulty and I used the Logcat from the android studio and it showed. Can you help now?

Comment: As stated in the error `Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.` Can you make sure you have `index.android.bundle` ready?

Comment: @Isaac After reading the Logcat I was able to deduce the problem too and found out that **index.android.bundle** was not generated with the build. So I created one and it worked. As I have recently dived into the world of react-native it was an enlightening error.

Comment: @Mesh: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @Andrew the logcat suggestion was great. Really helped (had an expo-update URL issue).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To those wanderers that face the same problem as I did, here's the solution:

i. Go to `[ProjectName]/android/app/src/main`

> (If the directory doesn't contain `index.android.bundle` inside of
>   `assets` folder, as not did mine. Then create a folder name
>   ***assets***. In case the files are present, delete the `index.android.bundle` file only.)

ii.  After navigating to your root project directory in your **Command Prompt** type -

```
cd android

./gradlew clean
```

iii. Go back to your root directory in your **Command Prompt** and type -

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

And it's done. Don't forget to sign your newly build react-native app tho.

Comment: The command for bundle copy some assets which will be duplicated.

Comment: Didn't worked. Just made a bunch of issues appear that after I fixed left me back at zero and all my icons disappeared

Comment: If you omit the `--assets-dest` then it won't duplicate the assets. In my case it seems like the only file missing was the `index.android.bundle` so just generating that was enough. Unclear why assets get copied but the actual bundling isn't done out of the box

Comment: Man....you save me life.

Comment: This saved my day. Generally used to refresh react native recent code into android studio

Comment: I have don't this step but also my app crash in other pone but work-in in my phone so what i can do here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990078/react-native-app-crashing-other-device-again-and-again-but-its-working-fine-in

Answer (score 10):

If possible use below in different terminal, issue will be showing on that terminal

```
adb logcat *:E
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also phase the same problem and solved using @Crypticsy answer but there is some add-on.

1. Go to [ProjectName]/android/app/src/main

> If assets folder not present then create a new folder called `assets`

2. Then goto root directory of your project then run command:-

> ```
> cd android
>
> ./gradlew clean
> ```

3. Then goto root directory of your project then run command:-

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

If above command through `bash: react-native: command not found` then run with `npx`

After this when you synced this project in android studio it will through error `duplicate resources`

Then hit below command from root project.

> rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
>
> rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw
>
> ./gradlew clean

Now Generate Signed Bundle from Android Studio and works.

Answer (score 4):

-- this method is working for me --
**solution for  -  realesed app craching immediately on your device**

---

following `adb logcat` error
[image: following adb logcat error]

---

and following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'cli'

---

1  - .https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

```
-  `./gradlew bundleRelease`  <- generate error using this code


 after
```

2. - `cd android`
     (goto android folder using terminal and type)
   - `./gradlew clean`
3. go to main project root (cd..)-

- `cd..`
  (goto to your main root react native project )
  -   `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

4. - `cd android`
     (again goto android folder using terminal and type)
   - `./gradlew  app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

   after that check  your android\app\build\outputs\apk\release folder

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was the `react-native-gesture-handler`. When I checked logs using `adb logcat` it was showing the following error

> Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange"
>   dispatched

solved it by doing `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` in root `App.js`.

For more info [check this](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/320)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after ejecting Expo project. Solved by adding a line into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/APP_NAME" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
....
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://url-to.update" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the suggestions given does not work, then try updating the Java version installed in your development system.