# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle

Tags: android, react-native

I am somewhat new to react-native and Android Studio (I am working on my first app).  The iOS version of my app is working fine.  However, I cannot say the same about my Android version.  I can run the Android app from react-native and from Android Studio without any issues in the emulators.  I can also push the app to my Android tablet via Android Studio, and the app works exactly as expected.  The problem comes in when I go into Android Studio and build my APK.  The release APS builds fine.  However, when I push it to the Google Play store (to a closed test), in Pre-launch report, all devices report the following error:

"Issue: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release."

The launch page loads and then the app immediately closes.  I have pulled the app to my Android tablet from the Google Play Store from my closed test, and I am seeing the same results from the APK.

2 days ago, I was able to upload a version of my app to my closed test, and that version was working.  I got an update pushed to me for Android Studio, and I have not been able to push a good APK to Google Play Store since.

I am completely lost, as I have tried everything that I can find on the web...and nothing seems to work.  Since I cannot reproduce the error locally, what is the best way to troubleshoot this.  Does anyone have any idea as to what could be causing this error?

Comment: follow this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855023/14951983](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855023/14951983), it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is for debug mode. you have to use **release mode** after generating signed apk. Please follow [the official react native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) to build the signed apk.

Comment: I have this setup and I am trying to test my release APK...same results...but, now I can at least see it on the emulator.  Anymore suggestions?  I am getting no errors on the build.

Comment: Additional information.  Following the article mentioned above, I can create a 'debug' APK file...which works correctly.  However, when I create a 'release" APK file, my app will launch and I see the splash screen...but then the app is immediately terminated.  Any ideas?

Comment: So this problem has been solved. you have another problem now. please mark my answer, then ask another question with the new error/log. This is the rules of stackoverflow. It's better to ask a new question about another problem. ask the question. We are here to have a unique answer for each question. <3

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will mark this answer, as it ultimately helped me solve my issue.  The link that you provided allowed me to be able to duplicate the issue locally....being able to test the Release APK file.  But, I still had the issue.  After a lot more searching, I stumbled across the following posting:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18357

If you scroll to the last post by remarcus, you will see the instructions that I followed to fix my issue.  Apparently, I  caused this issue when I applied an update to Android Studio or added something to my project.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I will check it.