# React-Native Android app signed APK/Bundle app crashes on launch

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

App used to work fine when signging a release `APK` or `.aab` file for PlayStore
I made small text modification to an alert and the release app now always crashes on launch
`debug-apk` works fine

PlayStore Stack Trace

```
 Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

Cleaning the project doesn't help

Also tried the solution here [React-native (Signed) release apk keeps crashing in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634072/react-native-signed-release-apk-keeps-crashing-in-device)

That didn't work either.

Someone help please